# ArrayFormula of Resetting Running Total in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, cumulative-sum

I'm looking for a (non-dragging) ArrayFormula of running total that resets every time the value in alt column changes. example:

```
          desired result
a    2          2
a    3          5
a    5         10
b    2          2
c    3          3
c    4          7
```

so every time value in the 1st column changes the sum resets. the table is always sorted if it matters.

---

non-reseting regular running total formulae:

- ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(ROW(B1:B6), "<="&ROW(B1:B6), B1:B6))
  ```
- ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(B1:B6)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B1:B6)))*B1:B6), SIGN(B1:B6)))
  ```

---

I was trying somehow to combine it with this counter formula but no luck so far:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(A1:A6, A1:A6, ROW(A1:A6), "<="&ROW(A1:A6)))
```

also I did some research, but only found either **[script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/112794/186471)** which I am **not** interested in or dragging/MS Excel formulae solutions like:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("L"&SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($H$2:H4=0)*ROW($H$2:H4)))+1):L5)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
=SUM(L$3:L5)-SUM(M$4:M4)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
=SUM($C$2:$C2)-IFERROR(SUM($C$2:OFFSET($C$1,LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:$B2="reset"),ROW($B$2:$B2)-ROW($B$2)+1),0)),0)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
=MOD((ROW()-ROW(E$1))*1,(1+5))
```

Comment: the ultimate goal is to do: `=FILTER(A1:B6, C1:C6<6)` (if it matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition, you could also try

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A:A),mmult(--transpose(if( (transpose(row(A:A))>=row(A:A))*(A:A=transpose(A:A)),B:B, 0)),row(A:A)^0),))
```

This should also work if the data is unsorted.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

modification of @JPV solution focused on **`speed`**:

```
=INDEX(MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))>=ROW(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))*(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))=TRANSPOSE(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))), 
 INDIRECT("B2:B"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))), 0)), ROW(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))^0))
```

[image]

shortened:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(x))>=
 ROW(x))*(x=TRANSPOSE(x)), OFFSET(x,,1), 0)), ROW(x)^0))
 (A2:INDEX(A:A, MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>"")))))
```

[image]

---

<s>`=INDEX(IF(B2:B="",, ROW(B2:B) - VLOOKUP(ROW(B2:B), FILTER(ROW(B2:B), B2:B<>"", B2:B<>B2:Boffset1), 1, 1) + 1)) - B=T/F.txt`</s>

Answer (score 1):

If the table is always sorted on column A, you can just do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(ROW(B1:B6), "<="&ROW(B1:B6), B1:B6)-SUMIF(A1:A6, "<"&A1:A6, B1:B6))
```

[image]

If the table is not sorted, you can still do it with a vlookup:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(ROW(B1:B6), "<="&ROW(B1:B6), B1:B6)-SUMIF(row(A1:A6), "<"&vlookup(A1:A6,{A1:A6,row(A1:A6)},2,false), B1:B6))
```

[image]