# Google Sheets - Running Total with reset

Tags: google-sheets, count, sum, transpose, cumulative-sum

Ok I have the following data from my brokerage:

| Amount | Description |
| --- | --- |
| -0.5 | EXCHANGE FEE |
| -0.09 | CLEARING FEE |
| -0.25 | COMMISSIONS |
| 20 | TRADE PAIRED |
| -0.5 | EXCHANGE FEE |
| -0.09 | CLEARING FEE |
| -0.25 | COMMISSIONS |
| 10 | TRADE PAIRED |

What I would like to do is having a running total that resets after it encounters "TRADE PAIRED" in the Description column. So it would look like this:

| Amount | Description | Running Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -0.5 | EXCHANGE FEE | -0.5 |
| -0.09 | CLEARING FEE | -0.59 |
| -0.25 | COMMISSIONS | -0.84 |
| 20 | TRADE PAIRED | 19.16 |
| -0.5 | EXCHANGE FEE | -0.5 |
| -0.09 | CLEARING FEE | -0.59 |
| -0.25 | COMMISSIONS | -0.84 |
| 10 | TRADE PAIRED | 9.16 |

Anyone have an ARRAYFORMULA that would be able to do this? I've been to do a continuous running total but it's not resetting after "TRADE PAIRED"

=ArrayFormula(if((G5:G<>"TRADE PAIRED"),MMULT(IF(ROW(D5:D)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(D5:D))=TRUE,1,0),if(G5:G<>"TRADE PAIRED",n(D5:D),0)),MMULT(IF(ROW(D5:D)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(D5:D))=TRUE,1,0),if(G5:G<>"TRADE PAIRED",n(D5:D),0))+D5:D)

This is not a duplicate of existing:
[ArrayFormula of Resetting Running Total in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58635231/arrayformula-of-resetting-running-total-in-google-sheets)

As that one is grouping based off a common value. Mine is resetting based on a specific value. Additionally, the formula provided in the link crashes Google Sheets

Comment: kinda same, tho. this part: `COUNTIFS(B:B, "TRADE PAIRED", 
 ROW(B:B), "<="&ROW(B:B))` will convert your "specific value" into a "common value"

Comment: @player0 Yes similar but not duplicate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A:A="",,MMULT(--TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(A:A))>=ROW(A:A))*(
 {0; ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(COUNTIFS(B:B, "TRADE PAIRED", 
 ROW(B:B), "<="&ROW(B:B)), ROWS(A:A)-1, 1)}=TRANSPOSE(
 {0; ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(COUNTIFS(B:B, "TRADE PAIRED", 
 ROW(B:B), "<="&ROW(B:B)), ROWS(A:A)-1, 1)})),A:A, 0)), ROW(A:A)^0)))
```

[image]

Comment: That appears to have done the trick and doesn't crash my sheet...ty!